# How to make this code work in ie browser- version 10?

Tags: css

```
nav ul li:hover 
{
     background:yellow;
}
```

The above code works fine in all the brosers except IE. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What IE version are you talking about?

Comment: IE8 does not recognize the :HOVER except on anchor tags. I would suggest adding the <A> inside the li and rely on a:hover.

Comment: sorry..it's ie 10 and the previous versions.

Comment: Are you in compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, `nav ul li:hover` should work in all browsers [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jhy2y/)

That only assumes there isn't any other CSS. Without knowing what the markup looks like though, you could try targeting the descendant anchor elements:

```
nav ul li a:hover {
    background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Didn't know it was this simple. Thank you!